# Question about electric field

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

Here the cavity must affect the electric field lines because there were electric charges in the cavity then removed , so the lines must change and be no more radially out ward due to asymmetry of shaded region that contains electric charge
So what is right and what is wrong?
The field lines must be different below from above due to irregular shaded shape not like the usual sphere
[image: 234333-20220708]

Comment: What is your question? I can't quite understand what you wrote. I also do not see a question mark anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

In a direct formulation of the problem, the question asks you to compute the electric field in a region when you are given the locations of all of the charges (the shaded region). The assumption suggests that the material is non-conducting and not a dielectric... so that there is no rearrangement of charges that can occur. *(Think of all of the charges as nailed into their locations in space, unless removed from the problem.)*

So, the direct calculation is to choose a point in the cavity
and compute the electric field vector there due to all of the charge-elements (in the shaded region).
Repeat for every point in the cavity.

While straightforward in principle, it looks difficult to carry out.

*(I won't say any more because I don't want to give away the solution or the strategy of the solution.)*

Comment: I know there is no rearrangment in charges location because the material is non-conducting but I've asked (the electric field lines towards the cavity won't change ? ) due to asymmetry of the shaded region and hence why we treat it like a normal sphere removing the cavity with no consider to the asymmetry of shaded shape , I thought it sould be no longer radially outward like the usual sphere so it may require some special way